# Another view on halachic conversion

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

The Shulchan Aruch says that candidates for conversion must do "Kabbalat Mitzvot".  [In this article](https://www.jewishideas.org/article/halakhic-conversion-non-religious-candidates), the author argues that this can be fulfilled by asking the candidate "Do you accept liability for not following the commandments?", as opposed to asking him "Do you to promise to follow the commandments?", given that many candidates will not follow an Orthodox lifestyle.  Are there halachic objections to this perspective?

Comment: Just to clarify there is a difference of accepting and commiting to the mitzvos vs. Keeping the mitzvos.

Comment: The concept of [Asmachta](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%90_(%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F)) seems relevant here.

Comment: @Maurice Mizrahi How about Avot 1:17, She'iltot d'Rav Achai Gaon 7:2, Sefer Tashbetz 1:146:1, Sefer HaIkkarim: Ma'amar 3, 28:5-7, Shnei Luchot HaBrit, Aseret HaDibrot, Shevuot, Torah Ohr 4:2, Likkutei Halachot, Yoreh Deah, Laws of Converts 3:19:1, and Pele Yo'etz 389:16? Accepting consequences is part of the other thing required of a convert, Kabbalat Ole Malchut Shamayim. But fulfillment of the commandments (kiyum) is essential.